# Cannot close socket pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to close a socket when the user presses ctrl-c. This works fine if the socket is still doing something. But when the socket is done with it's job and is doing nothing and I press ctrl-c nothing happens. By the way I am using windows 8.1.

Here is my code:

```
# close socket ctrl-c
from signal import signal, SIGINT
def sigint_received(signum, frame):
    s.close()
    exit(0)

# register SIGINT callback
signal(SIGINT, sigint_received)
```

When I try this code I have the same issue :

```
OriginalExceptHook = sys.excepthook
def NewExceptHook(type, value, traceback):
    if type == KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit("\nExiting.")
    else:
        OriginalExceptHook(type, value, traceback)
    sys.excepthook = NewExceptHook
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: can you show the code where your socket is doing `something` or `nothing`? is that in a loop?

Comment: yes it's a while(1){waiting for data} loop.

Comment: have you tried `raise KeyboardInterrupt`?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: see 
my answer for your info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re the comment, to use `except` for any unexpected `KeyboardInterrupt` will catch the "Ctrl+C" alike, what I meant is like:

```
while 1:
    try:
        ... your stuff here ...
        ... you should also break the while loop if no data is received ...
    # and except it when Ctrl + C like happens
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl C or alike is pressed..."
```